# Use of prototype to add a property to a function causes the function parameters to become undefined

Tags: javascript, sqlite, callback, prototype

I had a loop that did database calls (sqlite3) to reduce inventory in the callback. It worked fine, reducing whatever the "portionUsed" was by 1.

There could be from 1 to about 60 array elements on average, so this loop would create from 1 to 60 async tasks in rapid succession. The callback functions signature is (error, row) as determined by the JS binding to sqlite3. I can't change it.

```
     i = 0;
     while (i < struct.PortionsUsed.length) {
        portionUsed = struct.PortionsUsed[i];
        Db.get("SELECT blah blah WHERE portion = ? ORDER BY date LIMIT 1", portionUsed, selectCallBack);
        i++;
     }
```

The array containes lots of duplicate elements and sorting the array would, of course, place them all adjacent to each other so that a bit more logic could create a count of the number of "portionUsed" items to deduct from inventory in a single call, reducing the 60 tasks to about 10, so its worth doing. This means that the callback has to be given a count but there's no generic mechanism to supply it.

Closures won't work (tried it) because by time the callbacks fire, the count is the value of the last count in the loop. I needed to supply the current "count" at the time of callback task creation to be available inside the callback, so I tried to use a prototype extension to the callback function object to drag along a unique "count" per function by specifying a newly instantiated callback function per Db call.

```
     struct.PortionsUsed = struct.PortionsUsed.sort();  // Get all identical portion items adjacent to each other.
     i = 0;
     while (i < struct.PortionsUsed.length) {
        // i points at the first portion item, whatever it is.
        j = i + 1;
        while (j < struct.PortionsUsed.length && struct.PortionsUsed[i] === struct.PortionsUsed[j]) {
           ++j;
        }
        // j points at 1 past the last identical portion item.
        count = j - i; // count has the number of portions to deduct from inventory.

        // Get the oldest Portion row and reduce the qty by the count.
        portionUsed = struct.PortionsUsed[i];
        if (debug) {console.log('Starting Select for ' + portionUsed + ' - count=' + count);}
        selectCallBack.prototype.count = count;
        selectCallBack.prototype.portionUsed = portionUsed;
        Db.get("SELECT rowid AS rowNum, portion, qty FROM Portion WHERE portion = ? ORDER BY date LIMIT 1", portionUsed, new selectCallBack);
        //Db.get("SELECT rowid AS rowNum, portion, qty FROM Portion WHERE portion = ? ORDER BY date LIMIT 1", portionUsed,
        //   function(error, row) {count; portionUsed; selectCallBack(error, row);});
        i = j;
     }
```

The callback now won't work at all as both (error, row) are undefined. Why? How can I fix this? Inside the callback, this.count is available just as I wanted.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Here's the callback:

```
     function selectCallBack(error, row) {
        var count = this.count;                // made active ONLY when attempting to use prototype
        var portionUsed = this.portionUsed;    // made active ONLY when attempting to use prototype
        var portion;

        if (debug) {console.log('Hit selectCallBack. count=' + count + ' portionUsed=' + portionUsed);}
        if (debug) {console.log(typeof error + typeof row);}
        if (error !== null) {
           if (debug) {console.log('selectCallBack error:\n' + error);}
           success = false;
        } else {
           // real work goes here
        }
     }     // no return statement of any kind.
```

Closure Output:

```
   Starting Select for Coffee - count=5
   Starting Select for Hot Tea - count=2
   Hit selectCallBack. count=2 portionUsed=Hot Tea
   objectobject
   Hit selectCallBack. count=2 portionUsed=Hot Tea
   objectobject
```

prototype approach output:

```
   Starting Select for Coffee - count=5
   Hit selectCallBack. count=5 portionUsed=Coffee
   undefinedundefined
   selectCallBack error:
   undefined
   Starting Select for Hot Tea - count=2
   Hit selectCallBack. count=2 portionUsed=Hot Tea
   undefinedundefined
   selectCallBack error:
   undefined
```

Comment: *"Closures won't work (tried it) because by time the callbacks fire, the count is the value of the last count in the loop."* ...Then you were doing it incorrectly.

Comment: When you modify `selectCallBack.prototype.count` in the loop, all objects that have been created from `new selectCallBack()` will see the update. In other words, the `.prototype` object is shared between all instances, and so they all observe updates. Why not just put the property directly on the object you're creating?

Comment: ...if the third argument to `DB.get()` is supposed to be a callback function, you're not passing one when you do `new selectCallback` unless one is returned from `selectCallback` when you invoke it.

Comment: From your comments I realized that what I thought was the output from actually executing the callback function as a result of the Db call was in fact the output of my using the "new" on the function and consequently had nothing to do with the actual Db call. I realie now that the prototype method won't work at all since the new will execute it as a constructor.I updated the code to show what I tried to use as a closure attempt since you indicated I probably did it wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your closure attempt suffers from the fact that the only way to create a new variable scope in JavaScript is to invoke a function. While you are creating a function in the loop, all the functions are being created in the same variable scope.

To remedy this, you need to invoke a function in every iteration of the loop, pass in the value that needs to be held in that new variable scope, and create the callback function in that same scope. That way each function created in the loop is created in a unique function scope.

The clearest way IMO to do this is to move the code that needs the scope into a new function, and invoke it in the loop.

```
 struct.PortionsUsed = struct.PortionsUsed.sort();
 i = 0;
 while (i < struct.PortionsUsed.length) {
    j = i + 1;
    while (j < struct.PortionsUsed.length && struct.PortionsUsed[i] === struct.PortionsUsed[j]) {
       ++j;
    }
    count = j - i;
    portionUsed = struct.PortionsUsed[i];
    if (debug) {console.log('Starting Select for ' + portionUsed + ' - count=' + count);}

    setHandler(Db, count, portionUsed, selectCallback);

    i = j;
 }

function setHandler(Db, count, portionUsed, callback) {
    // In here, any of the above parameters can be used within the 
    //    handler function created below.
    Db.get("SELECT rowid AS rowNum, portion, qty FROM Portion WHERE portion = ? ORDER BY date LIMIT 1", 
           portionUsed, 
           function(error, row) {
               console.log(count, portionUsed); // Not sure how you wanted to use these
               callback(error, row);
           }
    );
}
```

---

A similar solution would be to only create the handler in our new function, and have the function return it.

```
 struct.PortionsUsed = struct.PortionsUsed.sort();
 i = 0;
 while (i < struct.PortionsUsed.length) {
    j = i + 1;
    while (j < struct.PortionsUsed.length && struct.PortionsUsed[i] === struct.PortionsUsed[j]) {
       ++j;
    }
    count = j - i;
    portionUsed = struct.PortionsUsed[i];
    if (debug) {console.log('Starting Select for ' + portionUsed + ' - count=' + count);}

    Db.get("SELECT rowid AS rowNum, portion, qty FROM Portion WHERE portion = ? ORDER BY date LIMIT 1", 
           portionUsed,
           setHandler(count, portionUsed, selectCallback)
    );

    i = j;
 }

function setHandler(count, portionUsed, callback) {
    // In here, any of the above parameters can be used within the 
    //    handler function that we create and return below.
    return function(error, row) {
       console.log(count, portionUsed); // Not sure how you wanted to use these
       callback(error, row);
    };
}
```

---

Some people like to do this with an inline, immediately-invoked function directly in the loop, but I think it clutters the code too much. I prefer using named functions.

Comment: You set me on the right path as soon as I saw you use the output of a function to return a function. That's what I was missing. I would have never thought of that. Thank You!